ערוך השולחן שולחן ערוך הרב
Does any one know if the aruch hashulhan quotes explicitly the shulchan aruch harav? If yes do you have a reference?
I have been told that the Mishna berura was the first one to do so in the litvish world (I don't have any reference)
Thank you

The Mishna Berura is before the Aruch Hashulchan. Indeed the AhSh quotes the MB sometimes, sometimes to disagree. (The AhSh is hence the Basrai.)

@DoubleAA according to wiki, the first pamphlets of both appeared in 1884.

@magicker orach chayim

Isn't there a sefer that aligned Mishnah Berurah, Kitzur Sh"A, Sh"A haRav, Aruch haShulchan and Chayei Adam?

0
I found a reference (by chance)! אורח חיים כ"ה כ"ג between parenthesis at the end of the Seif: (כן נראה לעניות דעתי. ועיין בארצות החיים ובמשנה ברורה. ודייק ותמצא קל.) but Not yet the S.A. Harav
